# What is the maximum z-level I can reach?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I have had a really excellent idea for a small megaproject (a kiloproject?), but I don't think I can see enough z-levels to build the whole thing.  It would need 20-30 above the ground, and IIRC I can only see about 10.  So, is there actually a hard ceiling (as it were) that I may run into, or will DF add levels as necessary so I can build as high as I care to?

Incidentally, my kiloproject is a red (bauxite) pyramid, topped with a black (obsidian) inverted pyramid, and maybe some stupid magma tricks.  My nobledwarves will be so pleased.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the ceiling **is** capped at 10 z-levels above the highest ground level on the map.

Basically, you want to look for an embark site that has a peak on it - you can flatten the mountain downwards to get enough "headroom" for your project.

Comment: An inspection of my map shows the peak of my mountain at +10 above ground level, and the highest z-level I can move to at +27, for a difference of 17 z-levels.  I'm not sure where 17 comes from, so that's weird.  I was mostly looking for whether there is a hard cap or not, and it would seem that I've found it.  Thanks!

Comment: @andronikus Ground level (or +0) changes based on where your cursor is.

Comment: Yes, I figured that out.  By ground level there I mean the lowest z-level with open space above ground.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that there is a tool in DFHack for extending the ceiling infinitely.  Not all at once, just a couple at a time, or maybe as many as you need.  This might increase lag, though, so use it carefully.

Comment: The DFHack command "infiniteSky n" will increase the Z levels of sky above your embark by n Z levels.